# How To Save The String Variable Data To Xml File

Tags: c#, web-applications

i am trying to develop a web application in c# but i want to ask that How do we save the string variable data to xml file ??

Hopes for your suggestions

Regards,

Comment: What are you exactly looking for? Do you have some XML file already to which you need to store some data or is it a new and you just want to use XML for data storage for your application?

Comment: i want to save string variable data to new xml file but ones it created it would be updated next time when the code run because string variable will contain some other data next time. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamWriter fsWrite = new StreamWriter(@"F:/info.xml"))
    {

        fsWrite.WriteLine("<ROOT>" +
            "<SIGN>1155</SIGN>" +
            "<MAXLOOP>23</MAXLOOP>" +
            "<TOTTAL_REC>5645</TOTTAL_REC>" +
            "<PART_EXPORT>retert</PART_EXPORT>" +
            "<LEAVE_EXPORT>retr</LEAVE_EXPORT>" +
            "<SAL_TDS_EXPORT>rter</SAL_TDS_EXPORT>" +
            "<HR_DET_EXPORT>rete</HR_DET_EXPORT>" +
            "<SELECTIONWISE>ertre</SELECTIONWISE>" +
            "</ROOT>");
    }
}
```

you can concatinate your string in this

and refer below site for other xml related options:

http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/xml/winform-xml-add-cs.aspx

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(strData);
                doc.Save(@"c:\LiveData.xml");

Comment: Deepi Your Given Link Helped Me alot !

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write all the text you want into a file using

```
File.WriteAllText
```

lets say your string is str...

```
File.WriteAllText("fileName.xml", str);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `XmlSerializer`

   ```
   public class Program
   {
       public class MyData
       {
           public string MyStringField { get; set; }

           public int MyIntField { get; set; }
       }

       public static void Main()
       {
           var data = new MyData { MyStringField = "Test", MyIntField = 1 };
           var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
           using (var stream = new StreamWriter("C:\\test.xml"))
               serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
       }
   }
   ```
2. `XDocument`

   ```
   var document = new XDocument();
   document.Add(new XElement("MyData", (new XElement("MyField", "Test"))));
   document.Save(@"C:\test.xml");
   ```
3. `XmlTextWriter`

   ```
   using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\test.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
   {
       xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("MyData");
       xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("MyStringField");
       xmlTextWriter.WriteString("Test");
       xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
       xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
   }
   ```

Notes:

- try to avoid writing XML as just `File.WriteText` as this will not validate XML and will not take care of escaping characters, for example `&`,`%`, etc.
- try to avoid using `XmlDocument`, use `XDocument` instead (assuming .NET 3.5 or higher).

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your quick reply your code is really ow sum as i am using Frame Work 3.0 i am not able to use XDocument is there some other simple code to save data from string variable to xml file as i think your Xdoucument code simple in all above mention code

Comment: @Syed Raza - so you already have XML in you string variable? You don't need to generate XML, you already have it, right? If so, do you need to validate that this is correct XML, before saving?

Comment: thanks for your reply it helps me alot i use a simple code like, XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(strData);
                doc.Save(@"c:\LiveData.xml");

Comment: @Syed Raza - with `XDocument` it would as simple as one line: `XDocument.Parse(strData).Save(@"c:\LiveData.xml");`

Comment: i am using frame work 3.0 thats why i do not use it

Answer (score 0):

1. [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx)
2. [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)
3. [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)
4. Serializer ([XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) or [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx))